# Delete element from list where sub-element matches string

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have this list:

```
persons_list = [tom, alice]
```

Where tom and alice are two instances of `Person`.
When I use `tom.sexe`, I get the string "Male" and when I use `alice.sexe`, I get her sexe, thus "Female". I may have others persons instances in persons_list.

Now, I would like to delete an element from the `persons_list` where sexe = "Male" in a one line shot, but I didn't succeed.

So far, I only manage to create a list containing only the age of the persons_list: `list(map(lambda x: x.age, persons_list))` , but it is different from what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a filter to rebuild the list:

```
persons_list = [person for person in persons_list if person.sexe != 'Male']
```

This picks out all objects that are *not* male.

Comment: Thanks you it was exactly what I was seeking for